# Impose a sorting rule for Nullable values using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects similar to the one below (`MyData` class) and I would use a LINQ query to get only those that meet a constraint on `SecondDate` property, and finally sort the items that meet this constraint on the basis of all properties.

```
public class MyData
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> FirstDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime SecondDate {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan SimpleInterval {get; set;}
    public double SimpleValue {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

I wrote the following query, but I do not know how to handle the `Nullable <DateTime> FirstDate` property. An item which has this property set to `null` should be sorted lower than another item which has identical values ​​of the fields except this property set to a not null value.

```
// public static void main
double threshold = ... // some initialization
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
...
var items = from item in list
            where ((now - item.SecondDate).TotalSeconds < threshold))
            orderby item.FirstDate descending
            orderby item.SecondDate descending
            orderby item.SimpleInterval descending
            orderby item.SimpleValue descending
            select item
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `HasValue` property, for example:

```
orderby item.FirstDate.HasValue descending,
        item.FirstDate.GetValueOrDefault() descending
```

Note that using multiple `orderby` clauses in a query expression is almost certainly *not* what you want to do - your query should probably be:

```
var items = from item in list
            where ((now - item.SecondDate).TotalSeconds < threshold))
            orderby item.FirstDate.HasValue descending,
                    item.FirstDate.GetValueOrDefault() descending,
                    item.SecondDate descending,
                    item.SimpleInterval descending,
                    item.SimpleValue descending
            select item;
```

Note that this is a good *general-purpose* solution, because it doesn't rely on the default value being lower / higher than anything in your data. `default(DateTime)` is actually equal to `DateTime.MinValue` in reality, but IMO it's nice not to rely on that, but separately say "I first want to bucket by null vs non-null, then the value". It also means that the non-null data is sorted before the null data *even if there are non-null `DateTime.MinValue` values*.

In your current query, it's effectively performing a new (stable) sort on *each* field, rather than only using it as a tie-breaker. If your previous query was giving you what you wanted, then you should reverse the order of the orderings (as it were):

```
var items = from item in list
            where ((now - item.SecondDate).TotalSeconds < threshold))
            orderby item.SimpleValue descending,
                    item.SimpleInterval descending,
                    item.SecondDate descending,
                    item.FirstDate.HasValue descending,
                    item.FirstDate.GetValueOrDefault() descending
            select item;
```

Consecutive `orderby` clauses are almost always a mistake, basically.

Comment: Isn't the `HasValue` call redundant in this situation, since `default(DateTime)` equals `DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: @rich.okelly: Nope - for one thing, it'll correctly sort all the non-null `DateTime.MinValue` results before all the null results. *Maybe* there aren't any such non-null results - but my code meets the requirements in a general way.

Comment: Very true, that check was in my original answer also before I removed it having convinced myself it was unnecessary... my bad!

Comment: Why could consecutive `orderby` clauses be a mistake? Perhaps because the last `orderby` _"overwrite"_ the previous ones?

Comment: @enzom83 Yes. The same result would be achievable by reversing the `OrderBy` and instead using `ThenBy`. In all likelihood if someone intended a `ThenBy` ordering they would use that method.

Comment: @enzom83: What Rich said :) Basically you've got `OrderBy(x).OrderBy(y).OrderBy(z)` when you probably mean `OrderBy(x).ThenBy(y).ThenBy(z)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Why I should reverse the order of orderings?

Comment: @enzom83: Well you haven't said what you really *want* the order to be. As you've currently written it in your question, the primary ordering is SimpleValue, and the *least* important property is FirstDate. Is that the way round you wanted it? If so, that's not the way most people would expect it to be written... and if you *actually* wanted FirstDate to be the most important bit, then your current code isn't giving you the results you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You're right, I would have to specify the order, but I thought it was specified implicitly in my query, ie: the most important property is `FirstDate`, and the least important property is `SimpleValue`.

Comment: @enzom83: Well you're specifying it, but you're doing it the wrong way round **because** you're using multiple `orderby` clauses. Even aside from the nullable aspect, your code doesn't currently work how it sounds like you expect it to.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Of course my code is wrong because I used multiple `orderby` clauses. However, your first query is what I wanted, that is: first `orderby` _non-null_ `FirstDate`, then by null `FirstDate`, then by `SecondDate`, then by `SimpleInterval` and then by `SimpleValue`.

Comment: @enzom83: Right. My point was that it wasn't clear whether you'd got your code in the order you wanted *aside from nullity*, in which case you'd have to reverse the orderings when you removed the extra orderby  clauses.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GetValueOrDefault method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx):

```
var items = from item in list
        where ((now - item.SecondDate).TotalSeconds < threshold))
        orderby item.FirstDate.HasValue descending,
                item.FirstDate.GetValueOrDefault() descending,
                item.SecondDate descending,
                item.SimpleInterval descending,
                item.SimpleValue descending,
        select item;
```

Alternatively, if you will not have any `FirstDate` properties equal to DateTime.MinValue, you could use the null coalescing operator, which may express the intent more clearly:

```
var items = from item in list
        where ((now - item.SecondDate).TotalSeconds < threshold))
        orderby item.FirstDate ?? DateTime.MinValue descending,
                item.SecondDate descending,
                item.SimpleInterval descending,
                item.SimpleValue descending
        select item;
```