# Is a null value in .NET DateTime guaranteed to be less than a real value?

Tags: .net, nullable

Perhaps my Google-Fu has failed me, but I haven't been able to determine if comparing a nullable in .NET will always be less than something else.

I've got some code similar to this

```
MyClass findLatest(List<MyClass> items){
    DateTime? latest_tstamp = null;
    MyClass latest_item = null;
    foreach(var item in items){
        if (latest_tstamp < item.tstamp){
            latest_tstamp = item.tstamp;
            latest_item = item;
        }
    }
    return latest_item;
}
```

It's seemed to work in the few limited cases I've tried (`item.tstamp` is declared `DateTime? tstamp` as well, of course).

Is this guaranteed behavior?

### Conclusion(?)

Based on the answers (and Jon Skeet's [answer on another question]), I've gone with the following check:

```
if (item.tstamp != null &&
    (latest_tstamp == null || latest_tstamp < item.tstamp)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294961/impose-a-sorting-rule-for-nullable-values-using-linq

Comment: @sixlettervariables, Jon Skeet's answer is actually more helpful for my situation than the question I asked. Hooray for crowdsourcing!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is behavior is guaranteed by the C# specification. The result of `<` on nullable value-types is `false` if any of them is `null`. Reference types on the other hand might exhibit different behavior.

Still I wouldn't recommend using this. It's hard to understand this code. I'd prefer an explicit `null` check, or just a boolean flag `isFirstElement` instead of using a nullable in the first place.

> **7.2.7 Lifted operators**
>
> *Lifted operators* permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> ...
>
> - For the relational operators
>        `<`   `>`   `<=`   `>=`
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. **The lifted operator produces the value `false` if one or both operands are `null`.** Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

*(Quoted from C# Language Specification Version 3.0)*

Comment: I guess I didn't really explain that my goal was to *find* the first element. I've got a list of "things" that have a timestamp, and because it's coming from a database `null` is a perfectly valid value. So I'm trying to find the item with the latest timestamp.

Comment: In that case I'd use an explicit `null` check.

Answer (score 6):

[Quote from MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one
>   of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons
>   evaluate to false except for `!=` (not equal). It is important not to
>   assume that because a particular comparison returns false, the
>   opposite case returns true. In the following example, 10 is not
>   greater than, less than, nor equal to null. Only `num1 != num2`
>   evaluates to true.
>
> An equality comparison of two nullable types that are both null evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it will never be `true`.  A comparison between nullable values where one of the values is `null` always produces false.  Hence the `if` comparison will never be true here and `latest_item` will never be set to a value

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition, you can call `Nullable.GetValueOrDefault()`

Example:

```cs
if (dateTime1.GetValueOrDefault() < dateTime2)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of compiler rules, the code isn't very readable.  You should definitely have null checking explicitly (IMO):

```
if (latest_tstamp == null)
```

Comment: I don't care what the `latest_tstamp` is - I'm trying to find the item with the 'largest' `.tstamp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not guaranteed to work for all types, because the `<` operator can be overridden to make sense for a specific class, and that code might not take null into account. For the standard operators for `Nullable<T>`, null will compare to be less than a value.

But if you are dealing with custom types, consider that their operators might not take nulls into account. For instance, look at this silly example:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo x = null;
    Foo y = new Foo();

    Console.WriteLine(x < y);
    Console.WriteLine(x > y);
}

class Foo 
{
    public static bool operator <(Foo lhs, Foo rhs)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Foo lhs, Foo rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I agree with the other answer here, that even though your code might work, it would be nicer to have explicit null checking.